# How to read from exact line to EOF

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a program that is supposed to enter text from file ( in .txt format) to Textbox1 when Button1 action clicked. But reading must start after line 6 (in 1,2,3,4,5,6 notation) or after line 5 (in 0,1,2,3,4,5 notation) and it should last till end of the file.

Comment: what do you have so far, show your code.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
File.ReadLines("C:\data\text.txt")
```

and bypass the lines you don´t need

```
Dim Lines = File.ReadLines("C:\data\text.txt")
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

' Start on Line 7 To Last Line
For i As Long = 7 To Lines.Count
    Dim line as String = Lines(i)
    sb.AppendLine(line)
Next

MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString())
```